# How to get control over AVPictureInPictureController Play/Pause button?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm using the Picture in Picture feature in my application using AVPictureInPictureController and its delegate methods. I followed the [APPLE](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_in_a_custom_player) documentation to implement this feature. And I'm glad that it's working fine.

But now I want to restrict the user to Play/Pause the content in some error cases. I tried hiding the controls in PIP mode(Picture in Picture mode) but I failed.

Is there any possible way to restrict the user actions ??

Or any other approach which will resolve my problem ??

Comment: Have you solved it?